# Why has my CSS rule been overridden?

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a media query telling my `footer` to have `background-color:none` only in Landscape. When in portrait it is a transparent red.
For some reason it is ignoring the landscape query. [image: Here is a screenshot from inspector.]

What could possibly be causing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem isn't with the media query, it's with the `background-color` declaration. `none` is not a valid value for `background-color`, so the declaration gets ignored and the `rgba()` value used instead.

To remove a background color, use `transparent` instead of `none`.

Comment: Mouse over the little ! icon and it'll say 'Invalid property value'.